# How to dynamically add .css to a custom Javafx LineChart Node?

Tags: java, css, dynamic, javafx-2, javafx

So, my issue is this: I'm attempting to define a custom set of nodes for a Javafx XYChart LineChart, where each node corresponds to a point that was plotted directly from the datasets. After looking around a little bit, Jewlesea actually had a solution at one point about how to add dynamic labels to nodes on a linechart graph that gave me enough of a push in the right direction to create black symbols (they are dots at the moment, but they can be many different things). Now I have a requirement that requires me to change ONE of the nodes on the XY chart into an 'X'. this could be either through loading an image in place of the 'node', or through physically manipulating the 'shape' parameter in .css.

The problem begins when I try to add this property dynamically, since which node has the 'x' will always be changing. Here are the things I've tried, and they all end up with no results whatsoever, regardless of the property used.

```
  private XYChart.Data datum( Double x, Double y )
  {
      final XYChart.Data data = new XYChart.Data(x, y);
      data.setNode(
          new HoveredThresholdNode(x, y));
      //data.getNode().setStyle("-fx-background-image: url(\"redX.png\");");
      data.getNode().styleProperty().bind(
        new SimpleStringProperty("-fx-background-color: #0181e2;")
        .concat("-fx-font-size: 20px;")
        .concat("-fx-background-radius: 0;")
        .concat("-fx-background-insets: 0;")
        .concat("-fx-shape: \"M2,0 L5,4 L8,0 L10,0 L10,2 L6,5 L10,8 L10,10 L8,10 L5,6 L2,10 L0,10 L0,8 L4,5 L0,2 L0,0 Z\";")
         );
      data.getNode().toFront();
      return data;
  }
```

So in the above, you can see that this is adding a property through the use of the 'bind' function after the dataNode has already been created. Also note above, I tried doing it through the 'setStyle' interface at this level to give it a background image, with no success. Also, no errors are being thrown, no 'invalid css' or anything of the sort, just simply no display on the graph at all when done this way.

now, in the HoveredThresholdNode (Again a big thanks to Jewelsea for being a master of Javafx and putting this bit of code online, it's where 90% of this class came from.) I tried essentially the same thing, at a different level. (actually being IN the node creation class, as opposed to a layer above it).

```
class HoveredThresholdNode extends StackPane {

    /**
     * 
     * @param x the x value of our node (this gets passed around a bunch)
     * @param y the y value of our node (also gets passed around a bunch)
     */
    HoveredThresholdNode(Double x, Double y) {
      //The preferred size of each node of the graph
      //getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style/XYChart.css").toExternalForm());
      //getStyleClass().add("xyChart-Node");
      //setOpacity(.8);
      styleProperty().bind(
        new SimpleStringProperty("-fx-background-color: #0181e2;")
        .concat("-fx-font-size: 20px;")
        .concat("-fx-background-radius: 0;")
        .concat("-fx-background-insets: 0;")
        .concat("-fx-shape: \"M2,0 L5,4 L8,0 L10,0 L10,2 L6,5 L10,8 L10,10 L8,10 L5,6 L2,10 L0,10 L0,8 L4,5 L0,2 L0,0 Z\";")
         );

      //this label is the 'tooltip' label for the graph.
      final Label label = createDataThresholdLabel(x, y);
      final double Myx = x;
      final double Myy = y;

      setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
          if (Myx == 0) {
            label.setTextFill(Color.DARKGRAY);
          } else if (Myx > 0) {
            label.setTextFill(Color.SPRINGGREEN);
          } else {
            label.setTextFill(Color.FIREBRICK);
          }
          label.setText("Current position: " + Myx + " , " + Myy);
          //setCursor(Cursor.NONE);
          toFront();
        }
      });
      setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
          //getChildren().clear();
          //setCursor(Cursor.CROSSHAIR);
        }
      });
    }
```

Now note, I also tried the `setStyle(java.lang.String)` method, with all of the same type of CSS, with no success. I have NO idea why this isn't styling dynamically. It's almost as if the custom nodes are simply ignoring all new .css that I define at runtime?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, please don't be shy if you need more details or explanation on any points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I did finally find a good workaround to solve my problem, although not in the way I thought it would happen. The main problem I was having, was that I was extending from stackPane to create my node, which only had a very small number of graphical display options available to it, and by switching the `'prefSize()'` property, I was simply changing the size of that stackPane, and then filling in the background area of that stack pane black, giving it a very deceptive shape-look to it.

So rather than use a stack pane, whenever I reached the node that I needed to place the red 'X' on, I simply called a different Datum method that returned a datum with an ImageView Attached, like so:

```
  private XYChart.Data CoLDatum(Double x, Double y){
    final XYChart.Data data = new XYChart.Data(x, y);
    ImageView myImage = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResource("style/redX.png").toExternalForm()));
    data.setNode(myImage);
    data.getNode().setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
          main_label.setText("Some Text.");
        }
      });
      data.getNode().setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
          main_label.setText("");
        }
      });

    return data;
  }
```

and since ImageView is an implementing class of Node, this worked out just fine, and allowed me to load up an image for that one single node in the graph, while still maintaining a listener to give custom text to our information label when the red 'x' was hovered over with a mouse. Sometimes, it's the simple solutions that slip right past you.

I imagine that, had I employed stackPane properties properly with the `setStyle(java.lang.String)` method, they would have absolutely shown up, and I was just butchering the nature of a stack pane. Interesting.

Hopefully this helps somebody else stuck with similar problems!